# Passing form inputs from different pages to submit at final page

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have 4 different pages both with one form each. 
I want to gather all the entries on each of the pages and submit once.
Here is code.

> ```
> Page 1
> <form action="page2" method="POST">
>     <input type="text" name="sex">
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
>
> Page 2
> <form action="page3" method="POST">
>     <input type="text" name="size">
>     <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
>
> Page 3
> <form action="page4" method="POST">
>     <input type="text" name="colors">
>     <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'] ?>" >
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
>
> Page 4
> <form action="verNote.php" method="POST">
>     <input type="text" name="likes">
>     <input type="hidden" name="colors" value="<?php echo $_POST['colors'] ?>" >    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
> </form>
> ```

Then i will like to get all the infos on verNote.php

> ```
> <?php
> echo $_POST['sex'];
> echo '<br>';
> echo $_POST['size'];
> echo '<br>';
> echo $_POST['color'];
> echo '<br>';
> echo $_POST['likes'];
> ?>
> ```

This code above dont seem to post entries from both pages 1 and 2, just for 3 and 4 alone gets submitted.

Will appreciate immediate assistance form anyone who understands my question.
Regards!

Comment: Ideally you would have each form post to a script that adds its data to the session, then the last form submit would recall all the data from session.  Quick way would be each form uses method=get and each next form collects data from the URL to populate hidden fields.

Comment: Can you paste a practical sample i can view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the hidden fields again each time

Page 3

```
<form action="B.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="colors">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'] ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Page 4

```
<form action="B.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="likes">
<input type="hidden" name="colors" value="<?php echo $_POST['colors'] ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $_POST['sex'] ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $_POST['size'] ?>" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand 100% what you're trying to achieve, but have you tried using sessions?

Do this in B.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( isset($_POST['sex']))
        $_SESSION['sex'] = $_POST['sex'];

    if( isset($_POST['size']))
        $_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];

    if( isset($_POST['color']))
        $_SESSION['color'] = $_POST['color'];

    if( isset($_POST['likes']))
        $_SESSION['likes'] = $_POST['likes'];
?>
```

Then you can retrieve the values from any other file, just call session_start(); and use the $_SESSION superglobal.

### EDIT

Using sessions, you verNote.php file could be something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['sex'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_SESSION['size'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_SESSION['color'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $_SESSION['likes'];
    echo '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: With this your code above, do i need to jst put in all other subsequent pages? do i need to still use hidden inputs in subsequent pages?

Comment: With this code you don't need hidden inputs, the values will be stored in the session and can be retrieved later from the same file or any other PHP file (verNote.php in you case), as long as you start the session (call session_start()) before using the $_SESSION superglobal.

Comment: Pls can you paste a practical sample i can view?

Comment: Sure, I've just edited my answer to include the code for verNote.php considering you'll be using sessions.

Comment: Using the above code you gave, i get error msg: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE) in ........

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a closing bracket to the ifs.